# Supporting different resolutions in PhoneGap(Android)

Tags: android, gwt, cordova

I am using GWT(google web toolkit) as my javascript library.I am using PhoneGap to convert it to a native Android app.My problem is that my project is 480px*320px (landscape) for a HVGA emulator which works good it takes up the whole screen.If I test on the WVGA800 emulator the project is considerably smaller which makes sense.

How can I compensate for both resolutions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out.What I had to do was set the follwing in the supports-screens in the manifest.xml

```
android:anyDensity="false"
```